# Optimal way of determining number of table entries that are duplicate on particular columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I need to determine whether particular table rows are unique on particular columns. Currently I'm doing this using a subquery like so:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable AS t2
        WHERE (t2.FirstName = t1.FirstName) AND (t2.Surname = t1.Surname)
    ) AS cnt
FROM MyTable AS t1
WHERE t1.ID IN (100, 101, 102);
```

Which works fine. However, I'd like to know if anyone knows of a more efficient way of achieving the same result than using a subquery.

I'm doing this on an Azure SQL Server, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a group by like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.Surname,
    COUNT(t1.ID) as cnt
FROM MyTable AS t1
WHERE t1.ID IN (100, 101, 102)
GROUP BY t1.FirstName, t1.Surname
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You can add a HAVING cnt > 1 after the GROUP BY clause if you want to filter only the dupplicates.

However, that depends if you need the ID column as well, if you do, you might have to use a subquery.

Here you can find more information on the subject:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: OP did say same results

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this will compare with your query in your environment but I would expect this to perform better:

```
Select id, qty
From mytable
Inner join
(
    Select firstname, surname, count(0) as qty
    From mytable
    Group by firstname, surname
) as qtytable
On mytable.firstname = qtytable.firstname  and mytable.surname = qtytable.surname
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a more efficient way would be to either use the COUNT function with OVER clause or ROW_NUMBER ranking function

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName, Surname) AS cnt
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (100, 101, 102)
```

OR

```
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName, Surname ORDER BY ID) AS rn
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (100, 101, 102)
```

> **ROW_NUMBER**  returns the sequential number of a row within a partition
>   of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported." Looks like Azure SQL servers don't support OVER. Sorry for not specifying I was using Azure SQL. I've updated my question to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

A little extreme but since need to use IN (100, 101, 102) twice then create #temp

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL);

insert into #temp([ID],[fname],[lname])
SELECT ID, FirstName, Surname 
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (100, 101, 102);

select t1.ID, t2.count 
from #temp as t1
join 
(
  select [fname],[lname], count(*) as count 
    from #temp 
   group by [fname],[lname]
) as t2
 on t1.[fname] = t2.[fname]
and t1.[lname] = t2.[lname];
```

Solution from Alexander is probably better
For sure it is less code